# Jira stories that are blocked by other project

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to write a Jira JQL filter that returns all issues in my project (named ABC) that are blocked by an issue in another project (named XYZ), or in any other project except my own ABC project.
First part of the filter that returns all stories in my project that are blocked, this is easy:

```
project=ABC AND issueLinkType = "is blocked by"
```

But from that list, I only want to see stories that are blocked from another project.
This works:

```
project=ABC AND issueLinkType = "is blocked by" AND issueLink in (XYZ-5021)
```

but then I need to know the IDs, so what I am looking for is more like the below examples that do not work:

```
project=ABC AND issueLinkType = "is blocked by" AND issueLink in (XYZ-*)
project=ABC AND issueLinkType = "is blocked by" AND issueLink in (project!=ABC)
project=ABC AND issueLinkType = "is blocked by" AND issueLink in (filter=12345)
```

Can this be done with normal Jira JQL? Is it possible  at all, maybe with some extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot perform that operation directly with naive Jira.

However, one of the most popular extension, `ScriptRunner`, has different JQL functions to help you.

You can check all the JQL Functions in ScriptRunner from [this link](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html).

`linkedIssuesOf` will help you about the JQL that you are trying to achieve:

`project = ABC and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("<some-filter>", "is blocked by")`